# Dart Template Request while creating a new Flutter Web Project in VS Code

Tags: templates, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-web

I am using the Ctrl+ Shift+P command in VS Code,like I have done many tie previously.  When the stagehand is done running, instead of asking for a Project Name, now VSC is asking "Which Dart Template"  I tried entering template names such as: package-simple, web-simple but nothing is letting me passed that point and when you click out of that field, the prompt disappears.  Any ideas on why this is happening? See screenshots for the exact view.

I've tried updating the stagehand, running package get, package upgrade, closing and restarting VSC

none specifically to show

See screenshots for info.

[image: New Flutter Web Proj]

[image: Which Dart Template]

Comment: Thanks for improving my post @dimitry-garazhny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an unfortunate bug caused by the move from the unforked version of Flutter's web apps (which used a Stagehand template) to the forked version (which uses `flutter create`).

To create web apps you can now use the standard **Flutter: New Project** command after enabling web support (see https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web - note that you must be on the master branch).

The **Flutter: New Web Project** command will be removed in the next update to the VS Code extensions. Sorry for the confusion and inconvenience!

Comment: Thanks for the update @danny-tuppeny I ended up creating a new dir in Linux manually, then in terminal running flutter create "project_name" and then opening the folder from the file menu in VS Code.  Once in the newly created project, I dropped in the flutter_web dependencies and updating the package imports and added a web directory and creating the missing files manually... sort of a long work-around, but it's working...

Comment: What should i do I am receiving the same issue to select dart template ?

Comment: @JayMungara the answer is above :) Use the **Flutter: New Project** command and see the link above. **Flutter: New Web Project** was a temporary fix while the web work was forked.

Comment: Can you tell me how can i deploy my flutter web project to server. also, I want to run my build project as a separate web project in chrome. Is it possible?

Comment: @JayMungara building for release is also coverd on the page above under the heading "Generate a release build". This is an early technical preview though, I would not recommend using it in production.